# separate views in different files while structuring jquery binds for large websites

Tags: javascript, jquery, design-patterns

I am trying to implement [this](http://www.viget.com/inspire/extending-paul-irishs-comprehensive-dom-ready-execution/) way to structure my jquery binds, it worked perfect.

I just have one question:
In the sample in the article he put all the views in one namespace called SITENAME, and like that all views should exist in one .js file, how can I put the views in different .js files?
for example:
To put common view in common.js file and users view in users.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespace `SITENAME` is just a JavaScript object.

If you have code like this:

```
SITENAME = {
  common: { ... },
  example1:  { ... },
  example2:  { ... }
}
```

You can change it to:

```
SITENAME = {
  common: { ... }
};
SITENAME.example1 = { ... };
SITENAME.example2 = { ... };
```

As you can see now the `example1` and `example2` objects are still defined inside `SITENAME`, but they are separated from the definition of `SITENAME` object itself.

So in your case you need to create your "namespace" object first (e.g. create app.js which will contain also some configuration stuff) and then you create separate .js files that will define own properties on already existing `SITENAME` object.

**Example:**

HTML:

```
...
<head>
  ...
  <script src="js/app.js" />
  <script src="js/example1.js" />
  <script src="js/example2.js" />
</head>
...
```

app.js (insert here common functionality, configuration, etc):

```
App = { ... };
```

example1.js:

```
App.example1 = { ... };
```

example2.js:

```
App.example2 = { ... };
```